# Android app does not indicate closed questions until after you open them

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, closed-questions

While browsing sites using the Android app, I came in a question I happen to remember being closed. From the question list view, there is no indication that the question is closed. The title does not bear the usual `[on hold]` or `[closed]` markers. Starting in 0.1.24 the question itself now includes a fixed banner at the bottom of the screen indicating the question is closed and abbreviated information about why. The interface for this is quite clean, but you still have to be in the question view in order to learn this.

**Edit:** The on-question banner is still too subtle. It should be at the top of the screen and yellow as in the main site rather than at the bottom and grey. Also as of the latest version there is *still* no indication whatsoever of closed questions in the question list.

Comment: What version are you using? The "closed" indicator was added in 0.1.24, so if you're using the newest version, this is a bug, but if you're using an older version, it's status-completed.

Comment: @balpha alright then for some reason I have 0.1.23, downloaded from the play store not 12 hours ago after getting my invite, and it doesn't show there is an update available.

Comment: 0.1.24 was pushed to the play store only about six hours ago, so it should appear shortly.

Comment: @balpha It's not unusual for play store releases to hit my country (Turkey) later than other places :( It has hit now and yes, 0.1.24 includes the feature as described. I have revamped this question to be just about one place the indicator is still missing.

Comment: Heads up: 0.1.24 has a bug that will crash the app when you view a closed question and then leave with about anything other than the back button. I'm pushing 0.1.25 right now to fix that.

Comment: @balpha I'm on 0.1.24 and I'm not seeing the [closed] in the question titles, but I am seeing the banner at the bottom.

Comment: @StevenV See the original version of this question, but 0.1.23 had no indicator at all and that's what it started out as, hence his reply to was that some indication was already added but I had an old version. I updated this to reflect only the relevant part (the question titles) which wasn't addressed by 0.1.24.

Comment: @caleb Ha! I just read the question and comments in the app, so I didn't go through the edits. Now I understand, thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @balpha so is this [meta-tag:status-completed] by now?

Comment: @balpha & Caleb So, this isn't actually [meta-tag:status-complete], considering the edits. It should either be reopened, or since the first version was basically completed, asked again separately, or better yet [this one reopened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199697/closed-and-duplicate-questions-should-show-what-has-been-appended-to-the-title-i), since it's not a duplicate of the completed part of this request.

Comment: @Geoff et all, as Hod mentioned in it's current state this is _not_ status complete, can we get that taken off? There is still no indication of question status until after you open it.

Comment: @Caleb you're correct - this one was lost in the shuffle.  I have removed status-complete

Comment: @HodofHod Geoff fixed the tagging on this.

Comment: I'm using Android version 1.0.57 on a Samsung Galaxy S4 phone and still have this problem. Being able to see [duplicate], [on hold] or [closed] beside the question would save a lot of time spent opening inactive questions. In addition, even though the pertinent message appears at the bottom of the screen, it's gray and easy to miss until I've read the bulk of the question. If this feature can't be implemented soon, perhaps the color of the message could be changed to something brighter.

Comment: This still is the case on 1.0.60

Comment: @guntbert and good chance it will also be the case in 6-8 years. Some things are simply not important enough. :(

Comment: I am also missing this feature. In fact I was just about to ask for it myself. The iPhone app does add __[on hold]__ to a closed question's title. And surely this is an easy fix?

Comment: If an SE dev isn't going to post a "maybe someday I'll look at this" somebody at least add a "me too" answer for 50 reps ;-)

Comment: I did not see this question and might have bumped it with a new one. Does that count?

Comment: @SimonKlaver I had an open bounty on this, but it expired without anything to award it too.

Answer (score 7):

This will be fixed in 1.0.79 (at least at parity with the iOS app).

Non-search question lists will display with `[migrated|duplicate|on hold|closed|locked|protected]` after their title.  Sorting by votes won't have that to mirror how things appear on the web (all the popular questions have some kind of status).  Search excerpts won't have information that because its not exposed in the API.

Comment: Waaaaa.... have you become an Android dev also?!

Comment: @nicael [I dabble](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A235711+%5Bandroid-app%5D+-%5Bios-app%5D)

Comment: Confirmed to be fixed, at least for the quick search I had just now.