# Closed and duplicate questions should show what has been appended to the title in the Android App

Tags: bug, android-app, closed-questions

Questions that have been closed (e.g. [this question on Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/158/how-can-i-prevent-applications-from-running-on-startup)) or put on hold should show the "[closed]", "[on hold]" or "[duplicate]" properly in the title of the question:

[image: screenshot]

Also, the "Closed as exact duplicate" has been historically replaced with "Marked as duplicate", which is what should show in the app instead of the former.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Duplicate of [Android app does not indicate closed questions until after you open them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196011)

Comment: @HodofHod That is not a complete duplicate, as there is anothee question below the image

Comment: That's a very old dup, from a time when the dup banner was in fact part of the post. More recent ones shouldn't have that issue (e.g. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54397/voice-call-problem)

Comment: ... or so I thought, but I don't see this request useful enough, given Brian's answer on the dupe, and the already-existing close banner on the bottom.